# LWC - Pass event to Aura Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I am trying to pass an event to my parent aura component however the message within the event is always undefined.

Aura:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <lightning:card title="Aura Hello World" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="messageFromLwc" type="String"/>
    <c:template_Window_Navigation_VF name="testName" ontestEvent="{!c.handlefireEvent}"/>
    Message from LWC: {!v.messageFromLwc}
</aura:component>

({
    handlefireEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var message = event.getParam('testMessage');
        component.set("v.messageFromLwc", message);
        console.log('event.getParam:', event.getParam('testMessage'));
    }
})
```

LWC:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC Hello World">
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            Hello, {name}!
            <lightning-button label="Fire Event" title="FireEvent" onclick={fireEvent} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Template_Window_Navigation_VF extends LightningElement {
    @api name;

    fireEvent(event){
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('testEvent', { testMessage: 'Hi there' });
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try sending your data using the `detail` property on the event's payload, something like this:

```
const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('testevent', { detail: { testMessage: 'Hi there' }});
```

instead of this:

```
const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('testEvent', { testMessage: 'Hi there' });
```

as you can see on [Send Events to an Enclosing Aura Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components) article. Also, one of the suggested best practices is to avoid upper cases on the event's name, as described in the [Create and Dispatch Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) article.

Hope it helps.